# Using promises with ajax in change events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

Say you execute an ajax request upon a change event like so:

```
MyClass.prototype.bindChangeEvent = function(){
  $(document).on('change', '#elementid', function(){
    var $element = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: '/someurl'
    });
  });
}
```

Now, in client code, How can you attach to that ajax promise the done/fail/always callbacks?

You can't return the promise from the ajax request because its only created on the change event.

Is there a way to create a promise ahead of time and tell jQuery to use that promise for a particular ajax request?

In other words, is there a way to do something like:

```
MyClass.prototype.bindChangeEvent = function(){
  var promise = new Promise;
  $(document).on('change', '#elementid', function(){
    var $element = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: '/someurl'
      promise: promise
    });
  });
return promise;
}
```

Comment: what is the use case and higher level problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: There are other ways of doing this such as passing the done/fail/always as arguments, but that doesn't seem as clean. It seems more object oriented to return a promise that clients of this code can tack on their done/fail/always concerns without worrying about how the binding of the change event is implemented.

Comment: But the event can occur numerous times so it's really not clear why you want to return anything or what end use case would be

Comment: The use case is to say "whenever this event occurs, issue this ajax request and call this call back on done/always/fail of that ajax request but to do so in an object oriented manner as opposed to functional (passing arguments around)". Perhaps asking to do things OO in js is where I'm going wrong. I was hoping there was a way to simply return an object that would be used for each event as the Promise. @trincot's answer is the closest to what I'm looking for but doesn't succeed because Promise's won't get retriggered. So perhaps this is a limitation of Promise objects.

Comment: Just call the callback. Or you could also set up custom events if you need it to interact with dom elements

Answer (score 1):

You can use the promise constructor callback:

```
MyClass.prototype.bindChangeEvent = function(){
  var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    $(document).on('change', '#elementid', function(){
      var $element = $(this);
      $.ajax({
        url: '/someurl'
      }).then(resolve, reject);
    });
  });
  return promise;
}
```

But be aware that once the promise has resolved, it will no longer be useful for notifying a second change, so you'll have to create a new promise after each change, meaning you'll have to call `bindChangeEvent` again. I'm not convinced this is more practical than just using the plain event listener pattern.